# Facebook Share Meta Tags

Tags: facebook, share, meta-tags

I have my meta tags working until I changed it to be appeared only when a certain page is loaded. 
This is my code:

```
        <title>
    Effro | <?php echo isset($metatitle) ? $metatitle : 'Homepage'; ?>
</title>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

<!--Facebook og -->
<meta property="fb:app_id"             content="1247181518629773" />

<?php
    if(isset($is_ref) && $is_ref):
?>

 <meta property="og:type"               content="website" />
 <meta property="og:title"              content="Effro - We Solve Your Ambitious Event" />
 <meta property="og:description"        content="This i s a test Description" />
 <meta property="og:image"              content="<?php echo base_url().'assets/img/Effro_Facebook_Share.jpg'; ?>" />
 <meta property="og:url"                content="<?php echo site_url().'talents/referral'; ?>" />

<?php
    endif;
?>
```

I tried Open Graph Object Debugger several times. But it is not picking up the values.

Comment: This is solved now. I have removed og:url and it works. Also if anyone wants to change meta tags for different pages in codeigniter insert them under relevant $this->uri->segment(n).